# Баг с переносом строки

Tags: html, css, sublime-text

Добрый вечер!

Недавно на ХэшКод'e проскакивала тема про некий баг, а именно:

если, при написании разметки, в текстовом редакторе, для обрыва строки используется Enter, то на странице в браузере, появляется отступ (особенно это касается изображении).

Если кто знает, как с данным багом бороться, подскажите пожалуйста, или может быть кто-то помнит в каком вопросе была затронута эта тема...

Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как говорилось, нужно "держать" элементы вместе:

```
<img src='...'><img src='..'>

<img src=''
><img src=''>

<img src=''><!--
--><img src=''>
```

И еще какой-то один прикол был с css. Не помню :(

Comment: Не совсем нравиться мне такой подход, люблю аккуратность в коде, а когда img'ы в кучу, то каша получается.

Может есть другой вариант?

Comment: @Astor float: left; как вариант.

Comment: @lampa, спасибо. Принято! Вам +

Comment: @Astor только поаккуратней с этим способом :)

Comment: А есть "подводные камни"...?

Comment: @Astor попробуйте убрать float: http://jsfiddle.net/TqPxE/

Comment: @lampa, не вижу проблемы...

Comment: @Astor, там ещё нужно нажать кнопку Run или Update, чтобы увидеть.